# Reinstalling windows 7 on a seperate internal hard drive, will this delete files from other internal hard drives?

Tags: windows-7, operating-systems

I have 2 internal hard drives. One is 160GB with windows 7 32bit on it and the other is 1TB with all my pictures, videos etc on it.

If I wanted to remove windows 7 and install a fresh copy on my 80GB internal hard drive, will this effect my 1TB hard drive in any way?

Comment: If you install it on your 80GB drive it will not affect your 1TB hard disk drive but you have to make sure while installing you are choosing the 80GB drive for it.

Answer (score 1):

No.

During the installation windows will ask which drive to use. If you specify the 80GB drive it will leave the other drive alone.  Your pictures, videos etc will be safe.

If you do not have a backup of the 1TG drive then consider:

1. Making a backup. Windows reinstallation will ask you, but a fire in the house, theft, power failure etc will not ask.
2. In unsure how to reinstall, remove the data cable to the 1TB drive (after powering down ofcourse. And reinsert it after reinstallation - Once more at a time the power is down).